# Creating dictionaries from list which contains the headers as elements

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

bit of a rookie **scraper** here, trying to make a dictionary out of **scraped** table.

I **scraped** a table using selenium, which didn't have different headers and cells, and now I am stuck with an appended list I made myself that features firstly the header names and then all the values such as:

```
list = [H1, H2, H3, ValueA1, ValueA2, ValueA3, ValueB1, ValueB2, ValueB3 ....]
```

My desired output is a list of dictionaries that features the first three objects as dictionary keys, and the next three as objects as dictionary values, and so on.

Thank you

Comment: So you want a list of dictionary where each dictionary contains exactly 3 elements?

Comment: I'd fix the source, since you're making the list yourself. Shadowing builtins is a bad practice. Consider using a different variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is a code request, I'll bite:

```
In [3]: l = ['asdf', 'qwer', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [4]: n_headers = 2

In [5]: [{k: v for k, v in zip(l[:n_headers], l[i:i + n_headers])}                            
         for i in range(n_headers, len(l), n_headers)]
Out[5]: 
[{'qwer': 2, 'asdf': 1},
 {'qwer': 4, 'asdf': 3},
 {'qwer': 6, 'asdf': 5},
 {'qwer': 8, 'asdf': 7}]
```

This'll end up slicing the list quite a few times, which you can avoid with the `iter()` trick:

```
In [9]: g = zip(*[iter(l)] * 2)

In [10]: hdrs = next(g)

In [11]: hdrs
Out[11]: ('asdf', 'qwer')

In [12]: [{k: v for k, v in zip(hdrs, h)} for h in g]
Out[12]: 
[{'qwer': 2, 'asdf': 1},
 {'qwer': 4, 'asdf': 3},
 {'qwer': 6, 'asdf': 5},
 {'qwer': 8, 'asdf': 7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if this is what you're looking for but for a 'list' of dictionaries:

```
i = 3
d={}
result=[]
while i < len(list): #Iterating over list

    d[list[i%3]]=list[i]
    i += 1
    if (i%3==0):  #Add to your list for every third element
        result.append(d)
        d={}
```

Output would be along the lines of

```
[{'H2': 'ValueA2', 'H3': 'ValueA3', 'H1': 'ValueA1'}, {'H2': 'ValueB2', 'H3': 'ValueB3', 'H1': 'ValueB1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of zip, iter.. Assuming 3 headers..

```
lst = [ 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'ValueA1', 'ValueA2', 'ValueA3', 'ValueB1', 'ValueB2', 'ValueB3', 'ValueC1', 'ValueC2', 'ValueC3' ]
grps = list( zip(*([iter(lst)] * 3)) ) 
[ dict( zip( grps[0], grps[i]) ) for i in range(1,len(grps))]
```

Output:

```
[{'H1': 'ValueA1', 'H2': 'ValueA2', 'H3': 'ValueA3'},
 {'H1': 'ValueB1', 'H2': 'ValueB2', 'H3': 'ValueB3'},
 {'H1': 'ValueC1', 'H2': 'ValueC2', 'H3': 'ValueC3'}]
```